# Should I deallocate std::map value if it is an OpenCV mat?

Tags: c++, opencv

I declared an `std::map` with the key as `size_t` and the value as `cv::Mat`. There are no problems with it and no problems with the insertion via `std::map::insert` and `std::make_pair`.

The only question is the following. Should I call `cv::Mat::release` or something like that to deallocate the Mat map values or not? I allocate the Mat on the stack and call `cv::Mat::clone` to insert its copy into the map (`m_zone_mats` is the map I described above):

```
cv::Mat m_back = cv::Mat(m_frame_height, m_frame_width, CV_8U, cvScalar(0));
const cv::Point2i* ppt[1] = { &z[0] };
int npt[] = { int(z.size()) };
cv::fillPoly(m_back, ppt, npt, 1, cv::Scalar(255));
m_zone_mats.insert(std::make_pair(m_zone_mats.size() + 1, m_back.clone()));
```

Comment: Assuming your reference counter is 0 (as it gets decreased by `.release()`) then the method will deallocate that particular `Mat`. You can use it if you you wish to free memory however, this will be true only f the `Mat` has been created via .`create()`. Note that also, when the `Mat` goes out of scope, it will be released.

Comment: Thank you, @eldesgraciado!
1. I came across that reference counter thing but I can't figure out what it means. My `m_back` Mat, which I later insert, is created by a contsructor and I don't know whether it's the same to `cv::Mat::create` or not.
2. You wrote the Mat will be released when out of scope. You meant `m_back`, didn't you?

I'm very sorry but I coudn't find the direct answer to my question in the comment.